# C++ creating a bitmap file - not supported for viewing

Tags: c++, bitmap

I'm setting up a program for graphics but for my starting test case for creating a bitmap. I seem to be getting a "file not supported" error when trying to view the image created. At first it was in the `bitmap.h` at `unsigned char color[3] = {(char)floor(blue), (char)floor(green), (char)floor(red)};` thinking the cast needed to be int, but that didn't budge.

color.h

```
#ifndef _COLOR_H
#define _COLOR_H

class Color {
public: 
    double r, g, b;

    Color() {};
    ~Color() {};
    Color(double _r, double _g, double _b) : r(_r/255), g(_g/255), b(_b/255) {}

    // omitted operator overloads and print method not used in test case
};

#endif
```

bitmap.h

```
#ifndef _BITMAP_H
#define _BITMAP_H

void savebmp(const char* filename, int width, int height, int dpi, Color* data) {
    FILE *f;
    int k = width * height;
    int s = 4 * k;
    int filesize = 54 + s;

    int m = static_cast<int>(39.375);
    int ppm = dpi * m; // pixels per meter

    unsigned char bmpfileheader[14] = { 
        'B', 'M', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 
    };

    unsigned char bmpinfoheader[40] = {
        40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 24, 0
    };


    // Unsure about this implementation - read more about bitmap creading
    bmpfileheader[2] = (unsigned char)(filesize);
    bmpfileheader[3] = (unsigned char)(filesize >> 8);
    bmpfileheader[4] = (unsigned char)(filesize >> 16);
    bmpfileheader[5] = (unsigned char)(filesize >> 24);

    bmpinfoheader[4] = (unsigned char)(width);
    bmpinfoheader[5] = (unsigned char)(width >> 8);
    bmpinfoheader[6] = (unsigned char)(width >> 16);
    bmpinfoheader[7] = (unsigned char)(width >> 24);

    bmpinfoheader[8] = (unsigned char)(height);
    bmpinfoheader[9] = (unsigned char)(height >> 8);
    bmpinfoheader[10] = (unsigned char)(height >> 16);
    bmpinfoheader[11] = (unsigned char)(height >> 24);

    bmpinfoheader[21] = (unsigned char)(s);
    bmpinfoheader[22] = (unsigned char)(s >> 8);
    bmpinfoheader[23] = (unsigned char)(s >> 16);
    bmpinfoheader[24] = (unsigned char)(s >> 24);

    bmpinfoheader[25] = (unsigned char)(ppm);
    bmpinfoheader[26] = (unsigned char)(ppm >> 8);
    bmpinfoheader[27] = (unsigned char)(ppm >> 16);
    bmpinfoheader[28] = (unsigned char)(ppm >> 24);

    bmpinfoheader[29] = (unsigned char)(ppm);
    bmpinfoheader[30] = (unsigned char)(ppm >> 8);
    bmpinfoheader[31] = (unsigned char)(ppm >> 16);
    bmpinfoheader[32] = (unsigned char)(ppm >> 24);

    fopen_s(&f, filename, "wb");
    fwrite(bmpfileheader, 1, 14, f);
    fwrite(bmpinfoheader, 1, 40, f);

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        Color rgb = data[i];

        double red = data[i].r * 255;
        double green = data[i].g * 255;
        double blue = data[i].b * 255;

        unsigned char color[3] = {(char)floor(blue), (char)floor(green), (char)floor(red)};

        fwrite(color, 1, 3, f);
    }
    fclose(f);
}

#endif
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include "color.h"
#include "bitmap.h"

int element;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int dpi = 72;
    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;
    int n = width * height;
    Color *pixels = new Color[n]; // look into smart pointers

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            // element position in pixels array
            element = y * width + x;

            pixels[element] = Color(23, 76, 210);
        }
    }

    savebmp("practice.bmp", width, height, dpi, pixels);
    // should generate solid blue image

    std::getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should have a good image to compare with the one you generated with your program to see exactly what is incorrect (use a hex viewer or editor).  Second, there are literally thousands of examples of basic bitmap writing in C++ (even C) -- why not use a working example first to create your class from?

Comment: took your code and created an image that can be opened by IrfanView.  The image is 24 BPP and is all blue.  What image viewer program are you using to open the image?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

Better `memset` those byte arrays to all-zeros if you're leaving holes. Are you sure of what goes in every byte? You should be.

I can only assume you're populating a [`BITMAPINFOHEADER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx) struct. Why not use the struct? Even if you don't have the header it's from, you can define it yourself and save yourself the confusion with the byte array.

Next, beginning with the line `bmpinfoheader[21] = (unsigned char)(s);` you appear to have an off-by-one. The field `biSizeImage` starts at the `byte` with index **20**, not 21. The off-by-one continues in your code from there on.

Lastly, pixels are stored row-by-row, then padded to a 4-byte alignment. You enumerate `pixels` across its height in the inner loop, so you're basically going column-by-column instead. And don't forget the padding! You can calculate how many bytes you need to pad with using:

```
4 - (sizeOfRowInBytes % 4)
```

Hope this helps you. You might find [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#cite_note-AlphaBitFields-6) useful.